# Check subfolders for any files

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need to check multiple folders for any files in them every 5 minutes and if any exist, then I need to move them.

This is what I've tried:

```
for /d %%a in (fldr1 fldr2 fldr3 fldr4) do (
    if exist r:\%%a\*.* (
        xcopy "r:\%%a" "c:\temp\" /q /s /r /y
        del /f /q r:\%%a\*
    ) else (
        echo %date% %time%
        ping -n 300 127.0.0.1 > nul
    )
)
```

But I get `0 Files(s) copied` all the time, even when there not any files and for every subfolder and in this example only 4 subfolders, but in reality I have about 40 and I need to be able to see when any of the files were copied and it runs every 5 minutes. I either need to suppress all those `0 Files(s) copied` messages or some distinguishable message when the file was really copied.

Comment: You are correct and this batch file was initially written on XP machine, but now on windows 7 and will be on 10 prolly in near future. And this is just a small piece of that batch file and wanted to tweak it a little bit. I looked at robocopy and it generating a lot more info than needed, it reports on every subfolder even if there was no files, etc. I will look at it again in case I missed something.

Comment: Looked at robocopy and it won't work, still need working solution or advise!